# How to resolve the java_home issue between kibana and groovy?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, environment-variables, kibana, java-home

Elastic Search Kibana is unable to accept JAVA_HOME variable set as

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_333**

so I changed it to

***C:\Progra-2\Java\jre1.8.0_333***

Now groovy is unable to accept the JAVA_HOME variable set to

**C:\Progra-2\Java\jre1.8.0_333**

I need help in resolving this issue!

Comment: Describe "_unable to accept_"

Comment: JAVA_HOME is currently set to ***C:\Progra-2\Java\jre1.8.0_333*** and if I try to launch groovy I see this error message:
C:\xxx\abc>groovyConsole

"ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Progra-2\Java\jre1.8.0_333
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment
to match the location of your Java installation."

And if I change JAVA_HOME back to ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_333***
when I try to launch it I see the following error message:
C:\xyz\aaa\elasticsearch-8.4.3\bin>elasticsearch.bat

"\Java\jre1.8.0_333 was unexpected at this time."

Comment: Have you tried with a JDK instead of a JRE?

Comment: Yes I tried JDK as well it didnt work. My guess is that issue isn't with JDK or JRE, the space between "Program Files" in the JAVA_HOME path is the issue.